# Передача словарей из модуля в модуль Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, область-видимости, словарь, импорт

Есть задача, передать *словарь* из локальной области видимости в глобальную, а после этого отправить в другой модуль.

В глобальной области видимости он задается пустым.
В одной из функций заполняется какими-то значениями и с помощью `return` отправляется обратно, в глоабльную область видимости.

Мне нужно эти вычисления, которые хранятся в словаре перебросить в другой модуль.
Через `import` я получаю пустой словарь.

Есть два модуля: `test2` (клиентская часть), `test` (движок)
ниже **пример клиента**:

```
from test2 import checking
guess = [9, 1, 5, 7]

step_checking = checking(guess=guess)
print('быки - ', step_checking['bulls'], 'коровы - ', step_checking['cows'])
```

**пример движка**:

```
_holder = [1, 2, 5, 7]

def checking():
bull = 0
cow = 0
for index_value in range(1, len(guess)):
    # print('Быков - ', bull, 'Коров - ', cow)

    print('сравнение числа', index_value, 'из списка guess')
    print(guess[index_value], 'предполагаемое число')
    print(_holder[index_value], 'загаданное число')
    if guess[index_value] == _holder[index_value]:
        print('число совпадает по индексу и значению = нашелся БЫК')
        bull += 1
    elif guess[index_value] != _holder[index_value]:
        if guess[index_value] in _holder:
            cow += 1
            print('такое же число имеется в списке = нашлась КОРОВА')
    else:
        print('Совпадений не найдено')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: _holder = [1, 2, 5, 7]

Comment: для начала, вовсе не нужно отправлять его обратно через return, чтобы изменить, если только вам не нужно возвращать его именно как значение функции. А так, попробуйте убрать '_'. Чтобы изменить словарь внутри функции, объявите его через `global _holder`, таким образом все его изменения будут изменять заданный в глобальном н.с. словарь

Comment: вообще вопрос не должен приниматься ибо кроме названия словаря нужно хотя бы несколько строк кода, т.е. [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

я отметил и прокомментировал строки, в которые внес изменения:

**main.py**

```
from q1212449_2 import checking


guess = [9, 1, 5, 7]
step_checking = checking(guess=guess)     # вызываем функцию 'checking' и передаем туда 'guess'
# ^^^^^^^^^^ <-- ^^^^^^^                  # результат вычислений 'checking' будет в 'step_checking'
print('\nбыки - ', step_checking['bulls'], ', ', 
      'коровы - ', step_checking['cows'])
```

**q1212449_2.py**

```
_holder = [1, 2, 5, 7]

#            vvvvv <--- принимаем 'guess' из 'main.py'
def checking(guess):                                                      # + guess
    bull = 0
    cow = 0
    for index_value in range(1, len(guess)):
        # print('Быков - ', bull, 'Коров - ', cow)
        print('\nсравнение числа', index_value, 'из списка guess')
        print(guess[index_value], 'предполагаемое число')
        print(_holder[index_value], 'загаданное число')
        if guess[index_value] == _holder[index_value]:
            print('число совпадает по индексу и значению = нашелся БЫК')
            bull += 1
        elif guess[index_value] != _holder[index_value]:
            if guess[index_value] in _holder:
                cow += 1
                print('такое же число имеется в списке = нашлась КОРОВА')
        else:
            print('Совпадений не найдено')

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv +++ 

    # после каких-то рассчетов формируем словарь '_dict'      
    _dict = {
        'bulls': bull,
        'cows': cow
    }
    
    # передаем словарь '_dict' в 'main.py'
    return _dict
    
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ +++
```

Answer (score 0):

Выше уже приведен код, который, безусловно реализует задачу.
А вообще нужно же понимать, что если уж пишите, воспользоваться return, то и пользуйтесь им. Почему его в вашем коде то нет?

Передаёте в функцию именованный параметр, а в функции он почему то не объявлен. Почему? Да и зачем он именованный там - тоже не понятно, значения по умолчанию то нет же, да и он нужен единственный так, что

```
step_checking = checking(guess=guess)
```

можно сократить до:

```
step_checking = checking(guess)
```

при условии, конечно что в функции будет объявлен входящий параметр.

Ну и конечно, return возвратит в любой модуль всё, что в нем указано. Если бы было в условии не пользоваться return, то тут можно было бы в этом модуле объявить глобальную переменную, и ее в функции изменять. Или объявить класс, и в нем переменную класса, тоже вариант.